# Is nesting possible with CSS (like it is with SASS)?

Tags: html, css, sass

This might be a very stupid question, but I couldn't find anything and it seems so obvious: is nesting with CSS possible like with SASS?

For example, I want to define a `h1` tag on a certain page, so I write:

```
body.certain_page h1 {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

So far so good. If I want this style to apply to more than one page, I would write:

```
body.certain_page h1, body.other_page h1 {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Now when you define a lot of rules this way, it gets very tiring. It would be so much easier to write something like this:

```
body.certain_page, body.other_page {
  h1 {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

Like a media-query. Why is that not possible? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as [@destroy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19569762/1542290) already answered, you cannot have nested selectors using CSS, that's why developers choose [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) preprocessors. The best thing you can do to minimize the CSS is my grouping common properties like

```
div, p, i {
   color: #f00;
   /* All the three elements will have the same color */
}
```

You can also declare the base properties right in the parent selector so that they can be easily inherited and you don't have to call them again and again on each..

```
body {
   font-size: 14px;
   font-family: Arial;
   color: #515151;
}
```

The above properties will be easily inherited by elements such as `p`, so you won't have to declare the `font-family` or `font-size` each time unless and until you want to have a different `font-family` for a particular element which can be over ridden by using a more specific selector like

```
.class_name p {
   font-family: Open Sans, Arial;
}
```

You do have universal selectors which will also ease up over lengthy selectors, like say you want to `color` `red` all the elements nested inside a specific element having a class called `.class_name` so instead of doing

```
.class_name p, .class_name div, .class_name fieldset {
   /* This is really bad */
}
```

Instead you can write the above as

```
.class_name * {
   /* Much better */
}
```

---

> Conclusion : Learn CSS Selectors, that's the only way you can figure
>   out and you can optimize your CSS yourself, while selectors totally
>   depend on the DOM, so there are no pre defined techniques but you
>   should keep the selectors simple, not over complicated, else you will
>   end up writing more and more specific rules which will lead to more
>   100 line of crappy CSS...

---

Also, [here's](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/?csw=1) an handy tool by Google you can always use to optimize the performance.

Comment: Selectors like `.class_name *` are not good for the performance because they cause the browser to search for the element with `class_name` class in **any** element's chain of ancestors.

Comment: Well, stars are not that bad, atleast for normal websites, they are never a huge hit to performance if your website is basic, high traffic websites like facebook google matters here, even SO uses `.spoiler:hover *`.. and yes, it is bad, but it depends, I tend to use `*` to reset `margin`, `padding`, `outline`, `box-sizing`

Comment: I think .class_name > * would be a better option, not saying it's a good option but probably better than .class_name *

Answer (score 6):

No, that's not possible now, that's why SASS lists nesting as a feature.

Comment: Haha I was about to answer and boom, mine was shorter, it was **NO**, it's not possible..............

Comment: That would be so helpful? Do you know why it wasn't introduced yet? Or a possible workaround / tricks to make my life easier? Thanks!

Comment: Not possible *yet:* it is currently drafted as CSS Hierarchies Module Level 3, so there's a possibility it may land in Chrome at some point.  The draft itself is currently coming up as 404, but you can read more (here.)[http://drublic.de/blog/tag/preprocessors/] Still, SASS FTW.

Answer (score 3):

With CSS Selectors 4, something similar will be possible with `:matches` pseudo-class:

```
:matches(body.certain_page, body.other_page) h1 { ... }
```

It is already available in Webkit/Blink and Gecko-based browsers (as `:-webkit-any()` and `:-moz-any()`, respectively), but only as an experimental feature. Until CSS Selectors 4 are adopted by most browsers, using CSS Preprocessors seems to be the only solution to prevent such self-repeating in writing CSS.